# CodeIgniter 'get' form action?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a form on a page (view) which the URL for it is:

> www.example.com/page?item=samsung-galaxy-nexus

My form on this page (view) is:

```
<form name="formsearch" action="<?php echo site_url(uri_string()); ?>" method="get">
<input id= name="search"name="search" class="filter-search" type="text" placeholder="Search Me"/>
<button type="submit" class="filter-button">Search</button>
</form>
```

So lets say I type in 'Microsoft' to my search and hit enter.  The URL + query strings I need it to go to would be:

> www.example.com/page?item=samsung-galaxy-nexus&search=microsoft

I can get it working with normal PHP, however I can't seem to get it to work in CodeIgniter.  I've also gone into the config.php and set query url's to true.

It should also be noted that if the current URL is:

> www.example.com/page?item=samsung-galaxy-nexus

If I do `<?php echo current_url(); ?>` it outputs

> www.example.com/?page

Notice how the ? has swapped places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this working at all.  In the end I used a CodeIgniter 3rd Party Helper found [here](http://getsparks.org/packages/query_string_helper/versions/HEAD/show):

Answer (score -1):

Go at: application/config/config.php (at around line 72) and change the

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

or

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

and it should work for you, if not try 'REQUEST_URI' or 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'

If you still having problems with this you can simply rebuild the $_GET request (in your constructor of your basic Controller ) like this:

```
 parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

Comment: If I put that into the action path, the page won't even load anything before the submit button is pressed

Comment: OK I got the  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET); somewhat working.. If I run the search from here: www.example.com/page?item=samsung-galaxy-nexus, it will load www.example.com/page?search=microsoft. However it still misses off my original query string